# POST fetch request - converting to JSON

Tags: php, reactjs, post, cors, fetch

I'm trying to make a post request from a react front-end to a php file.

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  let payload = this.state.email;
  fetch(`http://website.com/file.php`, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
      },
    body: payload
  })
  .then((response) => response.json() )
  .then((body) => {
    console.log(body);
    this.setState({
      email: body,
      message: 'Success!'
    });
  });
}
```

I am getting an error message instead of having the fetch request go through.

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: You have a CORS issue on your endpoint for the preflight (options) call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your server does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in response to a preflight request (OPTIONS). A CORS request will fail if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing.

Here are some great articles that explain how CORS works:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!  That explains it.

Comment: use no-cors instead of cors @lemonyellow

Comment: After changing `cors` to `no-cors` I got the following error message: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.  What might be causing that error?

Comment: may be the data which comes back is not valid json @lemonyellow